# Panel mount DC connector

Tags: dc, connector, cables

I have a pcb which gets power from a 12v adapter through a DC-jack like this one.[image]

Now that everyhting is working fine, i would like to make a housing for the project.

The housing i have has a front and backplate. In the front i made openings for a lcd screen and some other stuff.

In the back i thought of drilling a hole and pass the connector like this one
[image]

through the hole and to the DC-jack. But that won't look that nice i think.
So I looked online for other ways of doing this, and found a panel mount DC power connector.
[image]

If i place that connector on the backplate, how could i connect the back side of this connector to the DC-jack on the pcb? Do i need another type of connector? could i use something like a multi plug power cable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do in your case is mount the panel connector (last picture) in your case. Then solder wires to that connector (it is indeed ment for soldering wires, not for PCB mount) and solder the plug to the other end of the wires. Then you can use the connector that is already on the PCB to connect the plug internally.

[image]

Other option would be to solder the wires from the panel mount connector directly to the PCB.

Comment: This is a good idea picture. However it may be easier to suggest that the internal wires could be a ready made coax barrel jack cable with one end cut off.  One such as this https://www.amazon.com/Valley-Enterprises%C2%AE-2-1mm-5-5mm-Adapter/dp/B00DX6ZUBM/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1485514021&sr=8-9&keywords=DC+power+cable could be cut in half.

Comment: @Douwe66 thanks for the picture! i was hoping for something like that for ideas. I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

The picture you show, and hopefully, also the datasheet and product description on the website you've got it from, clearly show solder lugs, ie. you solder on a cable to this, and connect the other end to your PCB.